# Code Wars Persistent Bugger issue with if-statement not running for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

https://www.codewars.com/kata/persistent-bugger/train/javascript
I'm working on the JavaScript Code Wars Persistent Bugger problem. As seen in the code, my if-statement appears to completely ignore the for-loop within it.

Anything logged within the for-loop does not show, and anything logged outside the for-loop remained the same as if the for-loop wasn't there. I've tried researching the use of for-loops inside if-statements as well as existing solutions for this Code Wars problem, but did not see my issue being replicated. From my understanding, the if-statement should run through everything within it from top to bottom.

```
const persistence = (num) => {
    if (typeof(num) === 'number') {
        let count = 0
        let mult = num
        let newMult = 1
        let stop = false
        while (stop === false){
            if (mult >= 10) {
                for (let i = 0; i < mult.length; i++) {
                    newMult = newMult * mult[i]
                    // // doesn't log anything. code isn't running through for loop?
                    // console.log(newMult)        
                }
                // // logs initial num of 999
                // console.log(mult)
                // // logs initial newMult of 1
                // console.log(newMult)
                count++
                mult = newMult
                newMult = 1
            }
            else {
                stop = true
            }
        }
        return count
    }
}
// logs 1, should be 4
console.log(persistence(999))
```

I think I have the logic correct, but maybe there's some fundamental issue I'm missing in regards to how if-statements and for-loops work. I noticed there are much simpler ways to solve this problem, but if I could receive feedback on why my specific code doesn't work, and how I could tweak it to make it work, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating to the length of `num` on the for loop. As `num` is type number ,it has no length.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over a *string* version of `mult` (let's call it `multStr`) in order to access its numeric-indexed properties as digits. (Otherwise, it won't have a `length`, and accessing its numeric properties wouldn't give anything in return.)

You can also significantly clean up the code by returning early instead of having such nested blocks:

```js
const persistence = (num) => {
  if (typeof num !== 'number') {
    return;
  }
  let count = 0
  let mult = num
  while (true) {
    if (mult < 10) {
      return count;
    }
    const multStr = String(mult); // <--------------------------
    let newMult = 1
    for (let i = 0; i < multStr.length; i++) { // <--------------------------
      newMult = newMult * multStr[i] // <--------------------------
    }
    mult = newMult;
    count++
  }
}
console.log(persistence(999))
```

You could also consider using `reduce` to calculate the `newMult` instead:

```js
const persistence = (num) => {
  if (typeof num !== 'number') {
    return;
  }
  let count = 0
  let mult = num
  while (true) {
    if (mult < 10) {
      return count;
    }
    mult = [...String(mult)].reduce((a, b) => a * b, 1);
    count++
  }
}
console.log(persistence(999))
```